# Finding Numbers which add up to a square number

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, square-numbers

**Hello,**
I found a question in some old math's archive on the net which says,

> Find the ***maximum possible integral*** value of $n$ such that $4n^2 + 5n - 8$ is the **square** of an integer.

Now if we put it in an equation, we get $$4n^2 + 5n - 8 = \alpha^2$$ where $\alpha^2$ is the square number.

---

Inserting this equation into the quadratic formula gives $$ \dfrac {-5 \pm \sqrt {5^2 - 4.4.-(8 + \alpha^2)}} {2.4}$$ and further simplification gives, $$ \dfrac {-5 \pm \sqrt {153 + 16\alpha^2}} 8$$
Now the value of the $\sqrt{153 + 16\alpha^2}$  should be odd because if it is then $-5 + \sqrt{153 + 16\alpha^2}$ will become an even number and might be divisible by $8$ giving an integral value for $n$.

---

One possible value for $\alpha^2$ is $1$, but I'm not sure whether it is the largest possible value.
 So, i want to know if there is a way to find any other value for $\alpha$ such that $\sqrt{153 + 16\alpha^2}$ becomes an odd number.
***ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\;(2n+1)^2 = 4n^2+4n+1 \lt 4n^2 + 5n - 8 \lt 4n^2+8n+4 = (2n+2)^2\,$ for $\,n \gt 9\,$.

Comment: I don't understand the connection between the multiple lesser than and how it can become a hint. can you give a more detailed hint?

Comment: @user538335 An integer that is *strictly* between the squares of two *consecutive* integers cannot be a perfect square itself. This leaves you a few cases to check for $\,n \le 9\,$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i got an answer 9, but can you give an detailed explanation as to how you reached the solution?

Comment: @user538335 Don't think I have a `detailed explanation`, sorry. As far as heuristics, "*squeezing*" an integer between the squares of another two *consecutive* integers in order to prove that it's not a perfect square itself is a known technique, and given the expression here is a quadratic in $\,n\,$, it made sense to give it a shot upfront.